# What does “more physical” mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you please explain what does “more physical” mean?

The context is:

> Mr Ronaldo was football’s Rafael Nadal: less artistic, more physical, his career a triumph of sheer bloody-mindedness.

Is it something like “aggressive style of play”? ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/physical), in this sense it means:

> characterized by especially rugged and forceful physical activity